# Why are the inputs not changing the animation on keypress?

Tags: unity, animation, input

I have been following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wdOk5QXYC6Y&list=WL&t=1226s&index=21) tutorial. You can watch 16:00 - 18:20 to see what I am trying to do.

What should be happening is: I press a key, my animation plays and the parameters or Inputs get updated depending on which key I press. There are no errors in my script, but the parameters or Inputs are not updating. I have checked that I am using floats and that all my names match up. I've watched this part of the video and checked that my code was exactly like his multiple times. When using the model that he used in the video, the inputs *the inputs are working fine*. So would this mean there is something wrong with *my* animation, or is this an issue in my script?

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Animator anim;

    private float inputH;
    private float inputV;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("1"))
        {
            anim.Play("Armature|Walking", -1, 0f);
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("2"))
        {
            anim.Play("Armature|TurnRight", -1, 0f);
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown("3"))
        {
            anim.Play("Armature|TurnLeft", -1, 0f);
        }
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            int n = Random.Range(0, 2);

            if (n == 0)
            {
                anim.Play("Armature|Walking", -1, 0f);
            }
            else
            {
                anim.Play("Armature|TurnRight", -1, 0f);
            }
        }
        inputH = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        inputV = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

        anim.SetFloat("inputH", inputH);
        anim.SetFloat("inputV", inputV);
    }
}
```

[image]

Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: Can we see your input manager?

Comment: Hey again lol!!

Comment: I added the input manager. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Thus ones an easy fix. I brought this up before, but please consider going through the tutorials on the Unity website, first. This is the only way you will have suitable understanding of how core mechanics work - and they really are quite useful!

Comment: I'm asking this a lot these days but have you tried basic debugging? Your code works as well as it should, apart from the animator class which we have no knowledge in terms of how you're handling it. Try `Debug.Log("This input works.")` in the first input and test it that way.

Comment: @JohnHamilton, to give insight, this user had yroublesbwith setting up the animator and asked a separate question, accordingly.

Comment: @JohnHamilton I will try debugging. I tried adding a screenshot of my animator but my rep isn't high enough I guess. It's pretty simple though. It's just two animations pointing at one other animation. Nothing more than that.

Answer (score 0):

Your using `Input.GetKeyDown(string)`. If you check the API, you will note that the string should correspond to a key in the Input Manager.

In the Input Manager, you use names such as "Horizontal" and "Vertical". You make no reference to " 1" or "2". When you call `Input.GetKeyDown`, you should use the *exact names as they are printed*, or alternatively, use a `KeyCode`.

If you intend to use the Input Manager, look for input with commands such as `Input.GetKeyDown("Horizontal")` or `Input.GetKeyDown("Vertical")`. Note that it is *case sensitive*.  `Input.GetKeyDown("vertical")` will not trigger input on a key labelled " vertical".

If you intend to reference keys, directly, use `KeyCode`. *Every* key on the keyboard has an associated `KeyCode` enumeration value; `KeyCode.Alpha1` refers to the <kbd>1</kbd> button above the letters, for example, while `KeyCode. Keypad1` refers to the <kbd>1</kbd> button in your numeric layout, if your keyboard has one.

Comment: Will try to improve this answer when I have the software available.

Comment: GetKeyDown actually has a fixed set of strings it will use ([see the heading "Keys" at the bottom of this manual page](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ConventionalGameInput.html)), including values like "1" as described in the question. You may be thinking of GetButtonDown, which does use the names defined in the Input Manager.

Comment: @DMGregory, are you sure? I interpret that excerpt to be detailing the format you would enter them into the Input Manager, not as a list of alternate name conventions. The API specifically notes that the string format should match with an axis in the Input Manager

Comment: The API says "For the list of key identifiers see Input Manager." where input manager is a link to the root of the input documentation - so I think they meant "see this documentation page" not "look at the inputs configured in the editor's input manager." Bad wording, as is so often the case with those docs. ;) I just tested to be sure, using "space" (one of the named keys from the list I linked) and "Jump" (one of the default Input Manager entries, mapped to space). GetKeyDown responds to "space" correctly, and throws an ArgumentException complaining it doesn't know what "Jump" is.

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble following this convo. I'm just getting into Unity animation and there was nothing in the video that mentioned input manager and it worked fine for him. Later today I will be trying again using the same model that he is using. BUT, is the consensus now that I don't need to update the input manager? Again, having some trouble following this convo.

Comment: @MartinMarino It looks to me like the problem is not in how you are reading input.

Comment: I just tried the same thing with the model that he is using and everything is working as it should. I didn't do anything with the input manager. So I guess it's just my file.

Comment: If the UnityChan model I downloaded work and my own model is not working, does that mean it's an issue with my blend file somehow?

Comment: Upvoting this answer so Community stops pushing this 6 year old question. But future readers might want to check if they set up their AnimatorController correctly. Remember that the strings you pass to `Animator.Play` refer to animation states in the controller, not to actions.

Comment: @Philipp since this answer gives incorrect advice according to the test I described in the comments, I don't think upvoting is a good fix for the community bump in this case. Since OP mentions in the comments that the code works with another model but not their own, that indicates the problem is not in the content shown in the question but somewhere else. So I think in this case we can close it as not containing a Verifiable Example. That also solves the community bump without leaving a misleading upvote on incorrect advice that does not solve the problem. I've gone ahead and done so.

Answer (score -4):

Here is the original text, with which I've compared, up until now.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class player : MonoBehaviour  
{
    public Animator anim;
    public Rigidbody rbody;

    private float inputH;
    private float inputV;
    private bool run;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        rbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        run = false;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown("1"))
        {
            anim.Play("WAIT01",-1,0f);
        }
        else if(Input.GetKeyDown("2"))
        {
            anim.Play("WAIT02",-1,0f);
        }
        else if(Input.GetKeyDown("3"))
        {
            anim.Play("WAIT03",-1,0f);
        }
        else if(Input.GetKeyDown("4"))
        {
            anim.Play("WAIT04",-1,0f);
        }

        if(Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            int n = Random.Range(0,2);

            if(n == 0)
            {
                anim.Play ("DAMAGED00",-1,0f);
            }
            else
            {
                anim.Play ("DAMAGED01",-1,0f);
            }
        }

        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
        {
            run = true;
        }
        else
        {
            run = false;
        }

        if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Space))
        {
            anim.SetBool("jump",true);
        }
        else
        {
            anim.SetBool("jump", false);
        }

        inputH = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        inputV = Input.GetAxis ("Vertical");

        anim.SetFloat("inputH",inputH);
        anim.SetFloat("inputV",inputV);
        anim.SetBool ("run",run);

        float moveX = inputH*20f*Time.deltaTime;
        float moveZ = inputV*50f*Time.deltaTime;

        if(moveZ <= 0f)
        {
            moveX = 0f;
        }
        else if(run)
        {
            moveX*=3f;
            moveZ*=3f;
        }

        rbody.velocity = new Vector3(moveX,0f,moveZ);

    }
}
```

[Here is a [link][1](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/owpqvag1mztev3b/AABBW6WF_sstlfZdtmCv1uH_a?dl=0) for the complete project](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/owpqvag1mztev3b/AABBW6WF_sstlfZdtmCv1uH_a?dl=0).

Comment: Thus might be helpful, but it does not attempt to answer the actual question. Perhaps this would have been better, as a comment?

Comment: I appreciate the help, but all this info is in the youtube video that I already linked.